# Retrieve value from foreign key in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, foreign-key-relationship

I am learning ZF2 with the "[Getting started: A skeleton application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)" tutorial.

I update the table "album" with a foreign key "artist_id" whitch is connected to the "id" of a new table "artists".

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `artist_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_album_artists` (`artist_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_album_artists` FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `artists` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `artists` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the name of the artist from an album object **without sql join.**

**In controller**

```
// module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php:
// ...
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));
    }
// ...
```

**In the view**

```
// module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml:
foreach ($this->albums as $album) {
     echo "Artist's name : " . $album->getArtist()->name . "<br />";
}
```

How and where do I make the getArtist() method to do what I want?

Comment: Realy ? Nobody ? Maybe there is another way to do this. Please tell me!

Comment: Please tell my why not with join?

Comment: Dude use DoctrineORMModule and stóp using Zrnd\Db